# suitable monospace font

Tags: font-recommendation, monospace

in my current web project I am using Benton Sans as main font. It is all about a webapp dealing with numbers, which are displayed in matrices, whereby some should be highlighted and others greyed out.
Since there can be a lot of those matrices, with a lot of numbers in them (~80.000) I am looking for a monospace font, which suits well to the Benton Sans, but is also easily readable (especially for numbers) and comes in at least a regular and a bold cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Prestige elite: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/prestige-elite/
but maybe that's too classical, but the serif style monospace would create a good contrast to the sans-serif benton.

Also cool: Atlas typewritter: https://commercialtype.com/typefaces/atlas/typewriter

Doesn't benton have tabular opentype numbers? This way you could do everything in Benton ans still keep those matrices.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am not sure if about serif version but it also looks like a good idea, so i'm gonna give it a try!

Comment: Thanks again for the Idea with the serif version. Unfortunately the Prestige was a bit too "serify", but it lead me to "Average Mono", which for now does the best Job. http://openfontlibrary.org/en/font/average-mono

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Just as a background: Serif Monotypes have the advantage that they are much more balanced in the negative space because the typedesigner can react to the fixed grid with the serifs (e.g. the lowercase f uses it's horizontal lines to fill the grid which would otherwise result in ugly kerning).